# plague of the Firstborn

Tags: plagues-makkos

Are there any additional  sources as to why the tenth  plague (maakas bechoros) in Egypt was specifically directed at the first born? Were they more guilty than the rest of the Egyptians for enslaving the Jewish nation?
Ty

Comment: http://www.aish.com/atr/Why_First-borns_Killed.html